# How set title for UWP page

Tags: uwp

My requirement is that need a set title for[image] my UWP page

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Title bar customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar?tabs=wasdk) toturial. To add custom text to the title, set the ApplicationView.Title property to a text value, as shown below.

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Title = "Custom text";
```

Your text is prepended to the window title, which will be displayed as "custom text - app display name". To show a custom title without the app display name, you have to replace the default title bar as shown in the Full [customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar?tabs=winui2#full-customization) section.

Comment: For in my case title text is not showing as per the above code

Comment: I found solution , thanks for your support

Comment: You could post your solutuion as answer below and i will help to vote it up